# File_get_contents returning null/invalid format. when webservice which is been called returns an object

Tags: c#, php, web-services, rest, object

I have a C#(Rest Service) web service which returns an object.

```
public object[] GetObject()
{
object[] arr = new object[3];  
arr[0] = "String literal";  
arr[1] = 3;  
arr[2] = null;  
return arr;  
}
```

My Interface consists of following code

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/TestWcf", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
object[] GetObject();  //i tried including ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml also
```

My Php file which calls the web service consists of

```
$result=file_get_contents('http://example/TestWcf');
```

When i perform **echo $result;** its displaying the value but im not able to use it in the file or to perform any operation as it was taking null value.I tried using

```
$result = new SimpleXMLElement($result) ;//even $result[1]
```

but the **$result** value was null.Please help

Just wanted to add one more thing if the return value from the web service is string,int etc.. im getting the value n also can be used but when its object this problem exists

Comment: show your full code of this segment, there has to be something nulling the result.

Comment: $result=file_get_contents('http://example/TestWcf');  
    //echo $result;  
    $result = new SimpleXMLElement($result);  
    $return=redirectpage($result);  
    //echo $return;  
the $result will be sent to redirectpage function where in all this values are processed and redirect to a page

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to access the web service which required "**Authentication**"

For this kind of Web Services, you need to send the authentication details which are provided by Service providers in  request **headers**

Normally, you have to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) of [SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) protocols to do this.

Comment: But this works fine when return value is other than object i.e string,int...so am i missing anything?

Comment: I checked ,this is what i got
    - <ArrayOfanyType  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<anyType i:type="a:string" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">String literal</anyType> 
<anyType i:type="a:int" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">3</anyType> 
<anyType i:nil="true" /> 
<anyType i:nil="true" /> 
<anyType i:nil="true" /> 
</ArrayOfanyType>